# Is there a way to switch off the delay before icon and dropdown menu are shown next to filename in Preview.app?

Tags: preview, icon, big-sur

In Big Sur, the unified toolbar of Preview.app shows the file name, but not the icon and drop down menu next to it, unless I move the mouse onto it. This always creates a slight delay of about 200-300 ms and makes it really difficult to establish a good workflow when re-filing pdfs through drag and drop or renaming files, for example.

Is there any way to switch this off and see the file icon and dropdown menu all the time?

Here is an example of what I would like to see permanently and not only when I hover over the file name with the mouse:

[image: preview toolbar showing a file]

Comment: File a feedback request with Apple.

Comment: If you want to switch back to the pre **macOS Big Sur** style where the _title bar_ and _toolbar_ are stacked on top of each other, (the name of document is in the middle), then the following _command_ will do that. With **Preview** closed, in **Terminal** run the following _command_: `defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool false`

Comment: To change it back to the **macOS Big Sur** style, with **Preview** closed, in **Terminal** run the following _command_: `defaults delete ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle`

Comment: @benwiggy - yes, I did that already, however I was hoping for a quick fix

Comment: @user3439894 - great, that solves the problem for me, while I like the unified toolbar, it is just awkward to use

Comment: ukor, I've added my comments as an answer if you would like to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The officially recommended solution is to press and hold <kbd>shift</kbd> key, which will cause it to appear instantly when you mouse over it.

Comment: Thank you, funny, how this reverses the behaviour of the shift key in a way (as it usually slows down user interface animations, not speed up). However, it does not really help for quick navigation, as it still depends on the mouse hovering over the title. So I will stick with the solution @user3439894 offered in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch back to the pre **macOS Big Sur** style where the *title bar* and *toolbar* are stacked on top of each other, (the *name* of *document* is in the middle), then the following *command* will do that.

With **Preview** closed, in **Terminal** run the following *command*:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool false
```

To change it back to the **macOS Big Sur** style, with **Preview** closed, in **Terminal** run the following *command*:

```
defaults delete ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle
```